# Implement search bar into navbar?

Tags: html, css, searchbar

I currently have a navbar that is (and I'd prefer it to be) centered. However, throughout the completion of my website I completely forgot to add a search bar. I decided to use the code from W3Schools to incorporate the search bar to the right of my navbar without affecting any of the navbar texts (Home, Gaming, Office, Checkouts, Contacts), and on the same line as my navbar. How would I achieve this?

Here's my header:

```
  <header>
    <div class="number2">
    </div>

    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navlinks">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">H o m e</a></li>
          <li><a href="gaming.html">G a m i n g</a></li>
          <li><a href="office.html">O f f i c e</a></li>
          <li><a href="checkout.html">C h e c k o u t</a></li>
          <li><a href="contacts.html">C o n t a c t s</a></li>

      </div>
      <div class="searchbar">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
      </div>


    </div>

  </header>
```

CSS Code of Header and Search bar:

```
/* Style the search box inside the navigation bar */


.topnav input[type=text] {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600px wide, stack the links and the search field vertically instead of horizontally */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a, .topnav input[type=text] {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
  }
  .topnav input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
}

input[type=text]{
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  input[type=text]{
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
  }
}

/*---------END CART ITEMS------------*/

.navlinks{

}

.navlinks ul li:hover{

  transition: .5s;
  opacity: 100%;
}

.navlinks ul li{
  transition: .5s;
  opacity: 20%;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.img1{
  background-image: url(./assets/background/above.png);

}

.img1 .ple img{
  width: 700px;
  margin-bottom: -200px;

}


body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }


.navlinks li a{
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}
.navlinks a{
  color: white;
  z-index: 2000;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;

}

.navbar li{
      display:inline;
}

.navbar{

  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
}



header {
  background-color: #16161e;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:#16161e;
}

li {

}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;

  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;

}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  transition: 0.5s;

}

p {
    display: block;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
}

*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here's what it looks like so far:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set position:relative for your navbar and position:absolute for you search bar. Then you can position your search bar using right and top without changing your links.

Comment: Where do I add these? Which part of my code?

Answer (score 0):

For your navigation bar elements, I'd suggest using

```
letter-spacing: (x)px
```

instead of using spaces inside your  element in HTML. Also, you should change the `<div>` with the class navbar to a `<nav>` element (Both are better for SEO)

To answer your question:
This can be achieved by moving your searchbar into the  navbar container:

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="number2">
    </div>

    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navlinks">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">H o m e</a></li>
          <li><a href="gaming.html">G a m i n g</a></li>
          <li><a href="office.html">O f f i c e</a></li>
          <li><a href="checkout.html">C h e c k o u t</a></li>
          <li><a href="contacts.html">C o n t a c t s</a></li>
      <div class="searchbar">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
      </div>
      </div>



    </div>

  </header>
```

Next, we want to use `position: relative` on our container, and then `position: absolute` on the element that needs to be positioned, in this case it's the search bar.

CSS:

```
.navbar{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
  position: relative; /* add this */
}

input[type=text]{
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 0; /* add this */
  right: 0; /* add this */
  position: absolute; /* add this */
}
```

Full JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/kpLbgou8/

Answer (score 0):

I used flex to give you you're outcome. I also moved the break point to 1200 since the text is so large. Here's the CSS:

```
    /* Style the search box inside the navigation bar */

.navbar input[type="text"] {
  padding: 6px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
.navlinks {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto 0 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 2rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.navlinks a {
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 20%;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}
.navlinks a:hover {
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 100%;
}
.searchbar {
  width: 15%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .navlinks {
    display: flex;
    width: 100% !important;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }
  .searchbar {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  .navbar {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}


header {
  background-color: #16161e;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
}

p {
  display: block;
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-block-end: 1em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
}

*,
::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here's also a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-shannon-zufth?file=/index.html)

I removed some css so I could see what I was doing so you'll have to put it back in..